# how to add other columns to the resulting table when using a @ManyToMany?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

How can I add other columns in the resulting table from two entites that are mapped together with the @ManyToMany mapping annotation?

I have the two classes :

```
package com.rachid.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Project
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECT")

public class Project implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idProj;

private String projectName;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="projects")
private Collection<Employee> employees;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="matriculeChef")
private Employee chef;


public Project() {
    super();
}   
public Integer getIdProj() {
    return this.idProj;
}

public void setIdProj(Integer idProj) {
    this.idProj = idProj;
}   
public String getProjectName() {
    return this.projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}   

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
public Collection<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
public void setEmployees(Collection<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}
public Employee getChef() {
    return chef;
}
public void setChef(Employee chef) {
    this.chef = chef;
}


    }
```

and

```
   package com.rachid.jpa;

   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.lang.Integer;
   import java.util.Collection;
   import javax.persistence.*;

  /**
    * Entity implementation class for Entity: Employee
    *
    */
    @Entity
    @Table(name="EMPLOYEE")

    public class Employee implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idEmp;

@Embedded
private Personne personne;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="EMP_PROJ",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="PROJ_ID"))
private Collection<Project> projects;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="matriculeChef")
private Employee chef;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="chef")
private Collection<Employee> manaedEmployees;


@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
private User user;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="chefEntite")
private Entite entite;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="chef")
private Project projet;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
private Collection<Conge> conges;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idEntite")
private Entite entiteTravail;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="EMP_FORM",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="FROM_ID"))
private Collection<Formation> formations;

private String fonction;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Employee() {
    super();
}   
public Integer getIdEmp() {
    return this.idEmp;
}

public void setIdEmp(Integer idEmp) {
    this.idEmp = idEmp;
}   

public Collection<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}
public void setProjects(Collection<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public Entite getEntite() {
    return entite;
}
public void setEntite(Entite entite) {
    this.entite = entite;
}
public Project getProjet() {
    return projet;
}
public void setProjet(Project projet) {
    this.projet = projet;
}
public Collection<Conge> getConges() {
    return conges;
}
public void setConges(Collection<Conge> conges) {
    this.conges = conges;
}
public Entite getEntiteTravail() {
    return entiteTravail;
}
public void setEntiteTravail(Entite entiteTravail) {
    this.entiteTravail = entiteTravail;
}
public Collection<Formation> getFormations() {
    return formations;
}
public void setFormations(Collection<Formation> formations) {
    this.formations = formations;
}
public Personne getPersonne() {
    return personne;
}
public void setPersonne(Personne personne) {
    this.personne = personne;
}
public Employee getChef() {
    return chef;
}
public void setChef(Employee chef) {
    this.chef = chef;
}
public Collection<Employee> getManaedEmployees() {
    return manaedEmployees;
}
public void setManaedEmployees(Collection<Employee> manaedEmployees) {
    this.manaedEmployees = manaedEmployees;
}
public String getFonction() {
    return fonction;
}
public void setFonction(String fonction) {
    this.fonction = fonction;
}


   }
```

I need to add two columns in the resulting table **EMP_PROJ**

thanks for help

Comment: What would the two columns be useful for? Hibernate would ignore them.

Answer (score 5):

I would say than when you need to add attributes to an N-N relationship, you don't have an N-N relationship but a middle object with an 1-N relationship with each one.

Think of it in OOP terms... to which object would those properties belong? It could not be to either of the original ones, so a new one is needed.

Comment: for example in the resulting table I want to have the start date and the end date when the employee start working on the project until he finished, that is what I wanted to add as additional columns in the resulting table.

Comment: Then, as @SJuan suggests, an employee should have N Assignments, each having one project. The Assignment entity would have a start date and an end date.

Comment: yes but in the case when I am just interested in one object, but I need the second one, considering that I have a relation ship 1-N witch in this case one  employee has many projects that he or she is working on, the jpa will not generate the project table and that is not good  for me (at least because I need that table to store projects)

Comment: In either case, both `Employee` and `Project` classes/tables are created. What we are saying is that if you want data added to the relationship, a third class (mapped to a different table) will be needed.

Comment: so, what I understand from the suggestion is the have a relationship (1-N) @OneToMany from employee to project and to create another table to store the employee id, the project id, the start date and  the end date, isn't it?

Comment: No. From both `Employee` and `Proyect` you have a one-to-many to a, say, `ProjectAssignment`. It is in `ProjectAssignment` where you add the attributes that are part of the N-N (because it is what it really is)